Modify Java regex to find word preceeding a match
The regex \b(\w*)[[à-ü]|[À-Ü]]\b finds words ending with Spanish tildes (aka accents). For example, in "Tengo algún café" it matches algún and café.
I want to modify it so that it captures the word preceding the current match. For example, in "El mandatario celebró en sus redes", it should match mandatario. I'm particularly interested in a Java implementation of this regex.
I have tried using a capturing group as follows:
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b( \\w* )[[à-ü]|[À-Ü]]\\b");

and then extract String precedingWord = matcher.group(1);. However, this didn't work.

I think you need Pattern.compile("(?U)\\w+(?=\\s+\\w*[áéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ])") and then access the match using matcher.group(0)


For example, in "Tengo algún café" it matches algún and café.

No it doesn't. There's so much wrong with that regex, where to even start?
That's not what \b means
\b in basic mode is ascii-bound. So, you get this lunacy:
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\balgú\\b");
System.out.println(p.matcher("algún").find());

This prints... true. Which is lunacy, because it should print false. After all, there is no 'word break' after the ú in our input string. Indeed, replace that with a plain old ascii u and you get false as expected.
This is badly documented in the Pattern class. What is going on is that the pattern class is trying to be compatible with outmoded ascii-only concepts, even though java is nothing like that. Hence, ú is seen as 'not a word character' because it's not in the a-z range. We need to tell the regexp to not do stupid things, which we do with (?U) which turns on 'unicode mode'. then all is well:
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?U)\\balgú\\b");
System.out.println(p.matcher("algún").find());

Allright, finally, false. That's a start.
You forgot letters after the accented letter
You need to stuff another \w* in there. And you don't need the parentheses.
That's not how character classes work
This: [[à-ü]|[À-Ü]]
is gobbledygook. Inside [] most of the standard regex rules do not apply. - has a special meaning unless it is at the start or end (not true outside of [] where - just means -). . just means dot (outside [] it means 'any character'), + just means + and so on. In particular | just means bar:
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("H[e|a]llo");
System.out.println(p.matcher("Hello").matches());
System.out.println(p.matcher("Hallo").matches());
System.out.println(p.matcher("H|llo").matches());

That prints true... 3 times. Union (as in 'a or b') happens automatically inside character classes, and you need && (special meaning inside char classes) if you want intersection. So, you just want:
[à-üÀ-Ü]

Except you don't want that. There are a bunch of characters in the unicode table between à and ü. For example, ÷, and ø. Surely ÷ wasn't what you intended to capture there. Best to list them all out, explicitly.

finds words with Spanish tildes (aka accents)

Okay, so, that would simply be just ñ then: replace [à-ü]|[À-Ü]] with just ñ. Or if you do want to capture ú, something like [ñúíáé] - list them out. Relying on unicode ranges is asking for trouble. Trouble like accidentally including ÷ when you didn't mean to and the regex doesn't suggest this.
Don't re-list capital variants
You can just use the (?i) flag to turn on case insensitive mode.
Think about spaces better
You are mixing \\b and spaces and all sides in your 'I tried this but it did not work'. \\b already covers any spaces, you don't need to also include it. Unless you need to actually consume a space, which will come up if you want to match 'the word' and also match 'the word that comes after it which includes an accented letter'.
Let's review
We're at:
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?Ui)\\b\\w*[ñáúíé]\\w*\\b");

which will match any word that contains at least one accented character.
And now.. to match the word before it
You use positive lookahead for this:
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?Ui)\\b\\w+\\b(?=\\s+\\w*[ñáúíé]\\w*\\b)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("Tengo algún café");
while (m.find()) System.out.println("Found: " + m.group(0));

Note the inclusion of that \\s+ - we need to consume that space between Tengo and algún somewhere. Positive lookahead requires what's in the parens to be there, but doesn't consume it.
